# How to keep terminal session active after running a .sh script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python

I have a very simple `run.sh` script which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello, let's start!"
cd /Users/c/Dev/App/Code/
. venv/bin/activate
cd Backend
export FLASK_APP=app.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
export CONFIG=Local
flask run
```

After I run it, I get the following:

```
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Instead, I would like to get the active session as I would if I type the script manually, so simply the virtualenv active where I can then run `pip install` and see Flask's output.

How can I do that?

Comment: @pa4080 @karel @Eric-Carvalho @waltinator @Fabby: This question is not a duplicate of "Keep a program running in terminal". The question is about getting a active shell back after some program execution with additional environment settings (also typical for yocto).  That cannot be accomplished by `screen`, background task or nohup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a active session after the script, don't run it, source it:

```
$ source ./run.sh
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

$
```

You can also start a new bash/sh session in your script and add the environment variables there. But that complicates things...

Comment: Note that if the sourced script exits (with exit or with options such as errexit), the shell you used to source the script will also exit.